# present perfect and present perfect progressive

Tags: verbs, word-usage

There are times when either of these verb tenses could be used. For example, what is the difference in meaning between:  "I have learned English for two years"  and " I have been learning English for two years"?

Comment: In north American English, the first one isn't used so much. it appears that for states, the common north American uses the simple form (I've known him for years) while activities are used with the progressing (I've been learning), even if they aren't happening in the moment of speech.

Answer (score -1):

I have learned English for two years

suggests that you studied English and the process of learning is complete.

I have been learning English for two years.

suggests that you had started learning two years ago and are still learning.